# Convert Multiples Columns to a List inside a single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

I am using azure databricks, getting differents excel forms storaged in a blob. I need to keep 3 columns as it is and group as a list other multiples (and differents for each form) responses columns.

My main goal here is to transforme those diferents columns in one unique with a object that the keys are the title of the questions and the value is the response.
I have the following dataframe:

| id | name | email | question_1 | question_2 | question_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mark | mark@email.com | response_11 | response_21 | response_31 |
| 3 | elon | elon@email.com | response_12 | response_22 | response_32 |

I would like to have the following output.

| id | name | email | responses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mark | mark@email.com | {'question1':'response'11','question2':'response21','question3':'response_31'} |
| 2 | elon | elon@email.com | {'question1':'response'12','question2':'response22','question3':'response_32'} |
| 3 | zion | zion@email.com | {'question1':'response'13','question2':'response23','question3':'response_33'} |

How i could get that using pandas? i already did the following:

```python
    baseCols = ['id','name','email']
    def getFormsColumnsName(df):
        df_response_columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
        for deleted_column in cols:
            df_response_columns.remove(deleted_column)
        return df_response_columns
    formColumns = getFormsColumnsName(df)
    df = df.astype(str)
    df['responses'] = df[formColumns].values.tolist()
    display(df)
```

But this give me that strange list of responses:

| id | name | email | responses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mark | mark@email | 0: "response11"1: "response12"2: "response13"3: "['response11', 'response12', 'response13' "[]"]" |

i dont know what i should do to get what i expected. 

 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to make a function that takes a row and returns a dictionary

then apply it  to the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your `responses` column by using `pd.DataFrame.to_dict("records")`.

```
questions = df.filter(like="question")
responses = questions.to_dict("records")
out = df.drop(questions, axis=1).assign(responses=responses)
```

output:

```
   id  name           email                                          responses
0   1  mark  mark@email.com  {'question_1': 'response_11', 'question_2': 'response_21', 'question_3': 'response_31'}
1   3  elon  elon@email.com  {'question_1': 'response_12', 'question_2': 'response_22', 'question_3': 'response_32'}
```